# Python reportlab - How to draw something on the last page of a SimpleDocTemplate?

Tags: django, python-3.x, view, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm trying to create an invoice with the python reportlab library in a Django view.

But now my question:

> How can I write/draw something **at the bottom** (that's important!) of the last page? (Which may also be the first one, depending on how long the table is.)

My idea was to just get the last page's canvas and draw the footer on it (I added a Spacer so I can be sure that there's enough space for it. This would work, but I can't get the last page's canvas.)

```py
buffer = BytesIO()

doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, rightMargin=10*mm, leftMargin=10*mm, topMargin=10*mm, bottomMargin=0*mm)
elements = [Spacer(1,75*mm),get_table(),Spacer(1,108*mm)]
# get_table() returns a Table object

doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=draw_header)
# draw_header draws the header on the canvas

draw_invoice(CANVAS) # here's my problem

buffer.seek(0)

return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=False, filename='invoice.pdf')
```

Is there a way to get the canvas of the last page after building the doc and modify it? Or is there an other way to solve my problem?

Here's a scratch of what I'm trying to do: (The table could also go over more than 2 pages, the footer just **has to be on the bottom of the earliest possible page**, but after the table.)

[image: What I'm trying to get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find my own solution:

I created my own `Flowable` and added it with a `TopPadder` to the other `Flowables`. I had to put a `Spacer` between because otherways my `Flowable` was sometimes overlapping with the `Table`.

Answer (score 1):

I had several problems with reportlab, yes, it is a great tool to generate pdf but most of the times I had to override functions and creating subclass from basedoctemplate.

What I would do is create a pagetemplate that include that info, then swith to it before to finish the document with a Pagebreak().

```
class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
def __init__(self, data, filename, **kw):
    self.data = data
    self.allowSplitting = 0
    BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kw)

    #Frame bottom, limited to your work area
    frame_bottom = Frame(self.leftMargin, self.bottomMargin, self.width/2, self.height/2 - 20*mm,
                    page_height_landscape - 2 * self.bottomMargin,
                    id='landscape', showBoundary=0)
    # Definicion de templates
    template_last_page = PageTemplate('last_page', frames=frame_b,
                                       onPage=lastpage)
```

After that you can add your template_last_page to your doc. Then after to reach the final of the document use the method nextpagetemplate("your template"), then Pagebreak().

If you don´t use subclasses from the library is very limitated sometimes. I bought a reportlab book, Reportlab: Processing with Python, help me a lot with these kind of problems.

Regards.

Comment: That is ok. Thanks.

Comment: This didn't help me directly, but you gave me the idea to use BaseDocTemplate. I wasn't able to use your example, because I didn't really understand it, but you inspired me. Now I am at least able to print the real invoice on the bottom of the first page. (Which is is also acceptable for me, but on the last page, it would be better.) The problem with your answer is also that the real invoice may also be on the first page. (I'm going to add a screenshot of what I mean to the question.)

Comment: I changed the question a bit. If your answer would do what I want and I just didn't get it, please let me know. :) I didn't correctly write what I want, now, it should be easier to understand what I want. Thank you either :)

Comment: Thank you anyway* :D